# Eigenvalue based blob detector

Tags: algorithms

I jsut read up on the principle of centrality, where
"Think of a "network" as an NxN matrix, which has information about how N people (or N pages or N countries..) are connected to each other.

Adjacency Matrix is an NxN matrix, let's say it looks something like this. People who aren't connected to each other have A[i][j] = 0, people with weak relationships have A[i][j] = 0.1, people with medium ties have A[i][j]=0.4, 
people with strong ties have A[i][j] = 0.6
        1---2----3----4
1---0.0 0.1 0.4 0.6
2---0.1 0.0 0.4 0.0
3---0.4 0.4 0.0 0.1
4---0.6 0.0 0.1  0.0

1 and 2 are weakly connected, 1 and 3 have medium ties, 1 and 4 have strong ties. This is just a quick example to give you a quick idea. These matrices may not always be symmetric either.

People with "higher eigenvector centrality" are people who are better connected to each other."

Is it feasible to use this to locate blobs in images using their color relations to each other? I need a feature detector/ blob extractor that doesnt use corners so I saw this. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: 1. Your formatting didn't come out right.  I suggest you click "edit", then click on the ? in the upper-right to read through the formatting help, and fix the formatting on your question.  2. What have you tried?  Have you tried taking an image and applying this method to it, to see if it detects blobs or color relations?  3. What research have you done?  There's *lots* of research on blob extractors and feature detectors: dozens of papers, lots of textbooks -- what reading have you done?  What textbooks have you read?  Have you searched on Google Scholar?

Comment: everything except textbooks. ive tried all the famous ones

Comment: https://eciencia.urjc.es/bitstream/handle/10115/5743/ijcss01_01-083.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y someone beat me to my idea